# DotNetOpenAuth project + webform login with ASP.NET (VB.NET)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, entity-framework, oauth, forms-authentication

I have seen many DotNetOpenAuth project examples and many other very nice ASP.NET webform application with user management.

Unfortunately I could not find any example/project/chapter with the following aspects:

- Uses DotNetOpenAuth (e.g. for login with OAuth, FB, Twitter).
- No use of MVC or razor (Only ASP.NET 2 - 4.5 webforms).
- Uses SQL server (or SQL Express) for user and membership storage.
- Uses VB.NET and not c#.

Please don't suggest any project or pointer that can't match these 4 specific wishes, I have already checked these out the past weeks.
Please don't start a discussion on why this specific combination or that I should not use VB.net or should use MVC or other criteria mentioned :-)

The goal is to create an "empty" website with user login mechanisms already in place and have students concentrate on the stuff beyond the login part.